# Automatic Chart Pagination with Report Parameters

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, charts

Based on several report parameters in SQL Server 2005 reporting services, I would like to automatically generate one or several chart(s) for each row in the return result and paginate or space them out. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of charts will vary for each row, but the variations are known (e.g. it's either just chart 1, or chart 1 and 3, or charts 1 2 and 3) then it's simple enough using a table.

In the default detail row add any normal fields you need. Now insert a new detail row for each chart you might need. Lastly set the [visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337155%28SQL.90%29.aspx) of each chart row based on your rules, noting that the rule will **hide** the row if your expression evaluates to true. Make sure you select the **row** using the area to the left of the left-most cell, if you got it right you'll see that it's a row in the properties grid.

To get the layout you want you can merge cells for the charts to go in, or use a single cell and put a Rectangle in it, then in the Rectangle lay out your other controls.

Any rows that are hidden will be collapsed, so you wont get big empty sections like you can if you simply toggle the visibility of the charts themselves.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is place a [List control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121(SQL.90).aspx) on the page, set [List grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159660(SQL.90).aspx) by record unique key (ID, or several fields if composite), and place a charts on the List. Next, set items visibility expressions to [control it with report parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337155(SQL.90).aspx).